# Intranet LAN networking for office PCS

Tags: networking, file-sharing, lan, sharing, connection-sharing

I am a Newbie in Ubuntu.

I have 8 new PCs installed with Ubuntu 14.04, I am unable to do networking in them. I want to share files in all PC's Ubuntu to Ubuntu which includes sharing a drive and folder both which will be then accessed by all members in our LAN network when PC's are on.

I went for samba, followed all instructions made user, shared folder , changed the config file. Did everything but still none of the PC's are showing in network.

I also tried with Ubuntu to Windows sharing tutorials but didn't get any success...

More over IP messenger is also not working in 14.04 LTS

please help ...

Comment: Could you clarify your configuration : packages you've installed, config files, any other manipulation you've done to connect to the PC, ... or a link to the tutorial you've followed, ...

Comment: i have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for the first time

Comment: @Sonika Sharma: Do you have DHCP enabled?

Comment: @Renjuchingath no i dnt have that

Comment: @SonikaSharma : could you please explain about your LAN setup? How did you give IP to machines? Are you getting reply response on doing ping test?

Comment: @Renjuchingath Well the Router itself gives the IP. For more specific uses i reserve the IP in DHCP in router with the help of macid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets all pcs in the same IP range, by ip aliases:

```
sudo su 
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add these lines

```
    auto eth0:1
    iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

Ips for each successive computer: 10.0.0.1 -- 10.0.0.2 -- 10.0.0.3 -- etc.

Install the required packages:

```
sudo su 
apt-get update
apt-get install samba samba-common samba-common-bin smbclient system-config-samba nautilus-data
```

Set a password for each user in Samba on each computer:

```
sudo su
useradd -s /sbin/nologin <user_01>
smbpasswd -a <user_01>
useradd -s /sbin/nologin <user_02>
smbpasswd -a <user_02>
useradd -s /sbin/nologin <user_03>
smbpasswd -a <user_03>
etc. etc.
```

Create a directory to be shared and give permissions on each computer:

```
sudo su
mkdir /media/<user_name>/share
chmod -Rf 777 /media/<user_name>/share
```

Edit the file /etc/samba/smb.conf on each computer:

```
sudo su 
nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Once "smb.conf" has loaded, add this to the very end of the file on each computer:

```
[Share]
path = /media/<user_name>/share
available = yes
valid users = <user_01>, <user_02>, <user_03>, etc. etc.
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

Save a file: Control + O

Close nano: Control + X

Reboot

Comment: tried this but the following problem arises NO 1 :- The pc starts saying waiting for network configuration and then starts without network Then i have to undo the interfaces file to make it work again I am using this auto eth0:1 iface eth0:1 inet static address 192.168.1.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 network 192.168.1.100 broadcast 192.168.1.149 But this also doesnt work. NO2 - Nothing is visible in network ...the samba is correctly configured. But none of the 8 pcs are getting connected M i doing something wrong ? –